# How to write switch code better in java (smooth movement with exact numbers)

Tags: java, animation, smoothing

It's code to make smooth movement of a
 button in my game I'm trying to make
 in java. Is there a way to make this
 code smaller? I want these exact numbers,
 should I use array or something? Please can you give me some examples on how to make it simpler?

```
if(viewJumping == 1) {
        switch(viewGravity) {
            case 0:
                viewY -= 2;
                viewJumping = 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                viewY -= 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                viewY -= 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                viewY -= 2;
                break;
            case 4:
                viewY -= 4;
                break;
            case 5:
                viewY -= 8;
                break;
            case 6:
                viewY -= 16;
                break;
            case 7:
                viewY -= 24;
                break;
            case 8:
                viewY -= 32;
                break;
            case 9:
                viewY -= 40;
                break;
            case 10:
                viewY -= 48;
                break;
            case 12:
                viewY += 2;
                viewJumping = 0;
                break;
            case 13:
                viewY += 2;
                break;
            case 14:
                viewY += 2;
                break;
            case 15:
                viewY += 2;
                break;
            case 16:
                viewY += 4;
                break;
            case 17:
                viewY += 8;
                break;
            case 18:
                viewY += 16;
                break;
            case 19:
                viewY += 24;
                break;
            case 20:
                viewY += 32;
                break;
            case 21:
                viewY += 40;
                break;
            case 22:
                viewY += 48;
                break;
        }
        viewGravity -= 1;
    }
```

Comment: use the waterfall instead of repeating the same code
case 1:
                viewY -= 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                viewY -= 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                viewY -= 2;
                break; can be rewritten as:
case 1: case 2:
            case 3:  viewY -= 2;break;

Comment: Could i get a rough idea what you are trying to achieve may it might be not the best way to achieve it.

Comment: @Stultuske i was not knowing that fall through is also known as waterfall thanks.

Comment: it's usuall called fallthrough, but some teams tend to duplicate terminology, rather than learning (yet another) word ;) :D

Comment: @notyou nothing happens when you are at 11 or -1. When gravity is at 11 means the button is not moving and down, -1 means the button is not moving and up

Comment: @Stultuske that helps, thanks! I'll probably try to write it through array.. Wait a second I'll post a quick video of what does it look like -> https://youtu.be/nA7-K6hj68A

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about an array may lead to something like that:

```
int [] viewYs = {-2, -2, -2, -4 .....}
int newValue = viewY + viewYs[viewGravity]
```

And maybe simple `if/else` for your `viewJumping` parameter

Answer (score 0):

whatever the requirement you have i dont know.. but i have a bit better solution than yours.. take an array.. and use if else condition..

```
        int[] viewYArray = {2,2,2,2,4,8,16,24,32,40,48};
        if(viewJumping == 1) {
            if(viewGravity<=10)
            {
                if(viewGravity==0)
                    viewJumping = 2;
                viewY -= viewYArray[viewGravity];
            }
            else if(viewGravity>=12&&viewGravity<=22)
            {
                if(viewGravity==12)
                    viewJumping = 0;
                viewY += viewYArray[viewGravity-12];
            }
            viewGravity -= 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your values into a `Map`:

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(0, 2);
 map.put(1, 2);
 map.put(2, 2);
 map.put(3, 2);
 map.put(4, 4);
 ...
```

And then just update the values with a shorter `if...else`:

```
if (map.get(viewGravity) == null) {
    viewGravity = -1;
} else if (viewGravity < 13) {
    viewY -= map.get(viewGravity);
} else {
    viewY += map.get(viewGravity);
}
```

And then your `viewJumping` settings separate:

```
if(viewGravity == 0){
    viewJumping = 2;
}
if(viewGravity == 12){
    viewJumping = 0;
}
```